# Vulkan Framebuffer conflict on attachments image usage

Tags: attachment, conflict, framebuffer, vulkan

When I try to create a framebuffer via `vkCreateFramebuffer`, I get an error in my debug report callback about the conflict in `VkFramebufferCreateInfo` attachments. It says that my *image views* have a conflict in their image usages, while I don't expect this error because as a rule one of them must be a color attachment and the other must be a depth-stencil attachement.

The exact error message is:

> Framebuffer Attachment(0) conflicts with image's IMAGE_USAGE flags (VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT).

I even already have seen other examples, they are exactly the same.

My source code (Rust):
https://github.com/Hossein-Noroozpour/vulkust/blob/master/src/vulkan/swapchain.rs#L218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can explain how the error works. If in doubt it is useful to dig into layers source code:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/tree/master/layers

It would be issued on `vkCreateFramebuffer()`.

It would check the provided render pass and its subpasses vs the image views.

If a `VkImageView` is used at least once as an Input Attachment then it expects the `VkImage` of the `VkImageView` to have been created with `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_BIT`.

Similarly for Color Attachment with `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT`, and DS Attachment with `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT`.

Check that you meet these requirements.
Layer bugs are a thing too. If you are running the latest ones and confirm a bug, then reports belong here:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues

UPDATE (after seeing your source code):
I fail to see where you set `depth_reference.attachment`. You preinitialize it to `0`, so that could mean you assign the color attachment as depth to the subpass.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the images in the framebuffer is defined by the renderpass. Which means that if attachment 0 is used as a depth/stencil in the renderpass then the image needs to have been created with the `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT`

That means you need to double check the subpass descriptions you pass to the renderpass creation and make sure you haven't accidentally used attachment 0 as a depth.

Comment: Hi, my first attachment is a color image and the second is depth-stencil. if you want you can see my code here: https://github.com/Hossein-Noroozpour/vulkust/blob/master/src/vulkan/swapchain.rs#L218

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour I fail to find where you set `depth_reference.attachment` (and `color_reference.attachment` for that matter). (Updated my answer with the suspicion of what is going on now after seeing your code).

Comment: @krOoze tnx for your answer, for now my code is working fine but, I think there is a small chance to break in near future, if it doesn't matter, I'll keep this question as open question, till I get sure about it. (At first glance, I'll accepted your answer. :D)

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour There's no rush; validate if that works at your leasure. But don't reuse a SO Q if you get a different error (make a new Q, or you can visit at Khronos forum if you have a feeling it will lead to a prolonged discussion). FYI I am adding the SC link to your Q's text.